# Linked List Implementation with Interface

Tags: java, list, implementation

What i need to do in this assignment, is to implement the given methods from the interface. If you could check and give me some feedback on what i've delivered so far, would be very much appreciated.

I am still missing one method unfortunately, `public T getNext8thElementOf(int pos)`. Does anyone has an idea on how to implement it?

```
/**
 * A simple list interface
 * @param <T> The type of list element
 */
public interface ISpeedList<T> {

    /**
     * Returns the current number of elements in the list
     * 
     * @return Current number of elements in the list
     */
    public int size();

    /**
     * Inserts an element at the beginning of the list
     * 
     * @param item Item to be inserted
     */
    public void prepend(T item);

    /**
     * Returns the element at the specified position in the list
     * 
     * @param pos The position of the element in the list starting from 0
     * 
     * @return The specified element in the list
     * 
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException If the requested element is out of
     * range
     */
    public T getElementAt(int pos);

    /**
     * Returns the next 8th element of the specified element in the list
     * 
     * @param pos The position of the specified element in the list starting
     * from 0
     * 
     * @return The next 8th element of the specified element
     * 
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException If the requested element is out of
     * range
     */
    public T getNext8thElementOf(int pos);

}



public class SpeedList<T> implements ISpeedList<T> {

    /**
     * Doubly-linked node class, completely private to the List class,
     * as clients don't care about the implementation of the list.
     */
    private class Node {
        T item;
        Node next;
        Node previous;
        Node(T item, Node next, Node previous) {
            this.item = item;
            this.next = next;
            this.previous = previous;
        }
    }

    /**
     * The list itself maintains only a reference to its "header" node.
     * The header is a node that does not store any data.  Its 'next'
     * field points to the first item in the list and its 'previous'
     * field points to the last item.    This makes all insertions and
     * deletions uniform, even at the beginning and the end of the list!
     */
    private Node header = new Node(null, null, null);


    /**
     * The number of items in the list, stored to make size() O(1).
     */
    private int size = 0;

    /**
     * Returns the number of items in the list.
     */
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts <code>item</code> as the new first item.
     */
    @Override
    public void prepend(T item) {
        addBefore(item, header.next);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the item at the given index position.
     *
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
     *             if index not in [0,size).
     */
    @Override
    public T getElementAt(int pos) {
        return nodeAt(pos).item;
    }

    @Override
    public T getNext8thElementOf(int pos) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    //
    // PRIVATE HELPER METHODS
    //
    private Node nodeAt(int pos) {
        if (pos < 0 || pos >= size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(pos + " for size " + size);
        }
        Node n = header;
        for (int i = 0; i <= pos; i++) {
            n = n.next;
        }
        return n;
    }

    private void addBefore(T o, Node n) {
        Node newNode = new Node(o, n, n.previous);
        newNode.previous.next = newNode;
        newNode.next.previous = newNode;
        size++;
    }


}
```

Comment: No clue what *"next 8th element"* means in this context.

Comment: Probably this would be better on [Code Review.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)  Have you written any tests?  Can you show them?

Comment: What do you mean by "the next 8th element"? Do you mean "the element 8 after `pos`? If so, why not simply implement as `return getElementAt(pos + 8);`?

Comment: Sorry, by "next8thelement" it is meant that the two elements are connected, so it should return the next 8th element of the specified element.

Comment: @Jamie.L Since you didn't describe that, and you still haven't shown this "linking", how do you expect us to guide you in implementing that method? Other than the obvious: Locate element at `pos`, iterate from there comparing the elements to that initial element, decreasing a counter from 8, and return when counter reaches 0, throwing exception if end-of-list reached.

Comment: @Jamie.L More importantly, how do you know elements are "linked", when they can be *anything*, given that `T` is unbounded? What if `T` is `String`? Or `Integer`? How to you "link" those values? Because you can't be talking about the `Node` links of `next` or `previous`, because then it's just `getElementAt(pos + 8)`, given that node links define position.

Comment: Sorry, I don't clearly understand what the next 8th element is. Just return `getElementAt(pos + 8)`.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
@Override
public T getNext8thElementOf(int pos) {
    int eight = 8;
    Node nodo = this.nodeAt(pos);
    while(eight > 0) {
        eight--;
        nodo = nodo.next;
    }
    return nodo.item;
}
```